# references section - no indent in first line + formatting

Tags: cross-referencing, indentation

hope you can help me out with this one. here's the issue: I'm trying to create the references section in my paper. I already have a long list with the authors. But the problem is that the first line of the paragraph is indent, and the rest is no indent. However, as it is the reference section, I need the first line to be no indent and the rest of the paragraph indent. And all that should be done without using an outside bib tex file. Just plain style in the text.

I copy the header of my latex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[pdftex]{xcolor,graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf} 
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\Lagr}{\mathcal{L}}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{eucal}
%\usepackage[colorlinks = true,
%            linkcolor = blue,
%            urlcolor  = black,
%            citecolor = blue,
%            anchorcolor = black]{hyperref}
\geometry{left=1.0in,right=1.0in,top=1.0in,bottom=1.0in}
\onehalfspacing



And an example of my reference section:

\section*{References} 
\label{References}


Aguiar, A., McDougall, R., \& Narayanan, B. (2012). Global Trade, Assistance, and Production: The GTAP 8 Data Base. Center for Global Trade Analysis, Purdue University.
\vspace{0.2cm}


APEC (1997). The Impact of Trade Liberalization in APEC, Economic Committee, Asia Pacific Economic Cooperation, Singapore.
\vspace{0.2cm}
```

I really hope you can help me out hereby!!! thank you guys!!

cheers

Comment: You have many options. (1) Use a tool actually designed for creating bibliographies and reference lists (e.g., packages like `natbib` or `biblatex`); (2) use a package like [`hanging`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hanging?lang=en) to construct a 'hanging' environment; (3) use lower level commands like `\hangafter` and `\hangindent`. (Start with the first recommendation.)

Comment: thank you for the hints!! I'll check them out. But I don't have enough time to learn new packages for this issue, as I have to deliver the paper by the end of the week.... but for my next paper I'll definitely use a bib package...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use the `hangingparas` environment of the `hanging` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%%% I've commented out the packages that have no direct bearing on this question
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

%\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
%\usepackage[pdftex]{xcolor,graphicx}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\usepackage{pdflscape}
%\usepackage{wrapfig}
%\usepackage{array}
%\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
%\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
%\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
%\usepackage{color}
%\newcommand{\Lagr}{\mathcal{L}}
%\usepackage{footnote}
%\usepackage{threeparttable}
%\usepackage{subfig}
%\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage[font=small]{caption}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1in}

%\usepackage{eucal}
%\usepackage[colorlinks = true,
%            linkcolor = blue,
%            urlcolor  = black,
%            citecolor = blue,
%            anchorcolor = black]{hyperref}

\usepackage{hanging}

\begin{document}

\section*{References}

\begin{hangparas}{2em}{1} % first argument determines amount of haning indentation
Aguiar, A., McDougall, R., \& Narayanan, B. (2012). Global Trade, Assistance, and Production: The GTAP 8 Data Base. Center for Global Trade Analysis, Purdue University.

APEC (1997). The Impact of Trade Liberalization in APEC, Economic Committee, Asia Pacific Economic Cooperation, Singapore.
\end{hangparas}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you Mico!!! I tried it, works perfect... Now that you see my entire header in latex, I have a little question: how can I set the space in the text to 1.5, without changing tables that are inserted in the text?? Would be great if you could give me a hint... I've tried various possibilities, but they don't work properly...

Comment: @escazuwtf - Not sure I understand what you mean by "without changing tables that are inserted in the text". Loading the `setspace` package and executing `\onehalfspacing` should not affect the spacing in tables and footnotes, i.e., they should remain single-spaced. (You do want single-spacing in tables, right?)

Comment: I tried out the \doublespacing and it works fine. The tables aren't changed at all. I need the double-spacing feature. I think the 1.5 refers to double-spacing and not onehalfspacing?

Comment: @escazuwtf - Since your main document font size is `12pt` , `\onehalfspacing` corresponds to `\setstretch{1.241}` and `\doublspacing` corresponds to `\setstretch{1.655}`. If you were to execute `\setstretch{1.5}` directly, you'd get something roughly halfway inbetween `\onehalfspacing` and `\doublespacing`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint. Now I finally the difference. I'll check it out when I finished the whole paper. Then I can figure out which package I use. Thank you again and best regards

Answer (score 1):

Anyone who is not new to LaTeX will probably denounce my answer as a disgusting hack.  What I really should do is point you to a good resource to learn about at some of the tools LaTeX puts at your disposal to make it easier to manage your list of references.  However, I'm not sure how much of it you need for your use case.  For instance, do you treat the list of references simply as additional reading that the reader may wish to consult, or do you ever refer to the references in your text, as in "trade has been expanding rapidly, see APEC'97"?  If you ever do the latter, LaTeX has features to make it easier.  The answer I give below assumes you don't.

`\begin{thebibliography}{}
\item[~~~] Aguiar...University.
\item[~~~] APEC (1997). The Impact of Trade...
\end{thebibliography}`

Comment: If you're going to suggest use of a `thebibliography` environment, you should be using `\bibitem`, not `\item`. Moreover, you should still offer some hints as to how hanging indentation might be achieved when using this approach.

Comment: Re: bibitem: I said disgusting hack, didn't I?  (My excuse is that bibitem forces you to pick a key.)